# Addition of output file for renaming video batch

Tags: excel, ms-access, video, batch-file, frame-rate

With thanks to David Ruhmann, yesterday I got my batch file working for renaming videos:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Create Empty Folder
rd /Q "%Temp%\Temp" 2>nul & mkdir "%Temp%\Temp"

:: Loop through Folders
pushd "xPath=c:\processing"
for /d %%D in (*) do call :Process "%%~fD"
popd
goto End


::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:Process <Parent>
:: Folder Name
set "xFolder=%~nx1"

:: Set Sub Folder
if not exist "%~1\VIDEO\" goto :eof
pushd "%~1\VIDEO"

:: Loop through Videos
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir *.avi /b') do if exist "%%~fA" (
    set "xDateWritten=%%~tA"
    set "xDateGMT=0000/00/00 00:00:00"
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%X in ('robocopy . "%Temp%\Temp" "%%~nxA" /TS /FP /NS /NC /NP /NJH /NJS /NDL /L') do set "xDateGMT=%%X %%Y"
    rem Format = FF-FF-YYYYMMDD-HHh-MMm-SSs-FF-FF.ext
    echo %xFolder:~0,2%-%xFolder:~2,2%-!xDateWritten:~6,4!!xDateWritten:~0,2!!xDateWritten:~3,2!-!xDateWritten:~11,2!h-!xDateWritten:~14,2!m-!xDateGMT:~17,2!s-%xFolder:~4,2%-%xFolder:~6,2%%%~xA
    ren "%%~fA" "%xFolder:~0,2%-%xFolder:~2,2%-!xDateWritten:~6,4!!xDateWritten:~0,2!!xDateWritten:~3,2!-!xDateWritten:~11,2!h-!xDateWritten:~14,2!m-!xDateGMT:~17,2!s-%xFolder:~4,2%-%xFolder:~6,2%%%~xA"
)
popd
goto :eof


:End
endlocal
pause
```

But now I need to add an additional feature. After the renaming takes place, I would like the script to export the *new filename* followed by the *filesize in bytes*, and the *length of the video* to a csv or other excel-compatible filetype. As these are video files, if I could export the *framerate* and *total number of frames* as well, that would be great. Not sure if this is even within the scope of a batch file anymore though.

Comment: Is there a specific format that you want the size, length, framerate, and number of frames to be in?  Example: Length = 00h00m00s00ms or 00:00:00:00

Comment: size = bytes xxx,xxx,xxx
length = hh:mm:ss
framerate = xx
max frames = xxxxx

edit: and technically if we're pulling the frames, we dont need the duration, it was only going to be used to calculate the max frames if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a modification to export the name and size to a csv file.

Change this

```
echo %xFolder:~0,2%-%xFolder:~2,2%-!xDateWritten:~6,4!!xDateWritten:~0,2!!xDateWritten:~3,2!-!xDateWritten:~11,2!h-!xDateWritten:~14,2!m-!xDateGMT:~17,2!s-%xFolder:~4,2%-%xFolder:~6,2%%%~xA
ren "%%~fA" "%xFolder:~0,2%-%xFolder:~2,2%-!xDateWritten:~6,4!!xDateWritten:~0,2!!xDateWritten:~3,2!-!xDateWritten:~11,2!h-!xDateWritten:~14,2!m-!xDateGMT:~17,2!s-%xFolder:~4,2%-%xFolder:~6,2%%%~xA"
```

Into this

```
set "xFrame=00,00000"
for /f %%X in ('exiftool -p "$Framerate,$Framecount" "%%~fA"') do set "xFrame=%%~X"
set "xSize=%%~zA"
set "xName=%xFolder:~0,2%-%xFolder:~2,2%-!xDateWritten:~6,4!!xDateWritten:~0,2!!xDateWritten:~3,2!-!xDateWritten:~11,2!h-!xDateWritten:~14,2!m-!xDateGMT:~17,2!s-%xFolder:~4,2%-%xFolder:~6,2%%%~xA"
echo !xName!
ren "%%~fA" "!xName!"
echo !xName!,!xSize!,!xFrame!>>C:\RenameOutput.csv
```

**Update:**

To obtain the media file information we will have to use a 3rd party tool. Such as

1. [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)
2. [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en)
3. [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)

Based on a quick look at ExifTool and MediaInfo, I like MediaInfo better for its more consistent media file Duration output format.  Example of how to parse the information.

```
for /f "tokens=2,*" %X in ('mediainfo file.avi ^| find "Duration "') do @echo %Y
```

Update 2:

Added exiftool example to the answer.

Comment: close, but the duration being output is just giving me the ending time, rather than the actual duration of the video. for the test files im currently using, the video would have been started at 7:00 am, and ended at 7:30am, giving us a duration of 30 minutes give or take a few seconds either way.

Comment: @Shiken Ah, I see.  So you want the actual length.  There are two ways that we can get this information from what I know off the top of my head.  1. Through a third party command line tool for videos.  2. Length = Last Written - Creation Date (Which can be inaccurate if any modifications were made after the original write)

Comment: between /T:C, A, or W, none of those actually gives me 7:00am, so i don't think that method will work. whatre our options for the third party command line tools? i mean i can easily see this info if i right click the file and hit properties > summary, i just dont know how to get it into a simple spreadsheet for all the files in all the folders at once.

Comment: @Shiken  1. exiftool, would probably be my top pick ( http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/ , http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/RIFF.html )  2.  MediaInfo ( http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en ) or 3. FFMPEG

Comment: after fooling around with exiftool, the code
exiftool -csv -r -framerate -framecount %1 >> c:\processing\exifoutput.csv
gives me the information i need so far, now just figuring out how to merge it with the old code.

Comment: @Shiken  I have added to my answer about how to add the exiftool output.

Comment: Thanks once again, everything looks perfect now. I can now move onto my next project, pulling all of this into an access database. =)

Comment: Not sure if itll notify you of this comment but I need 1 last fix for this: i didn't notice because my test files were all AM, but the script renames PM files not in the 24 hour format that it needs to be.

Comment: I'll just make a new one since this is getting cluttered and theres another thing i forgot as well.

Comment: @Shiken  Yes, it does notify me.  **`:)`**

Comment: @Shiken  By the way, I have a solution for the 24 hours.  I have added an answer to this question to show you until there is a new question to post on.

Answer (score 0):

### This is in reply to our long comment stream.

Change this

```
set "xName=%xFolder:~0,2%-%xFolder:~2,2%-!xDateWritten:~6,4!!xDateWritten:~0,2!!xDateWritten:~3,2!-!xDateWritten:~11,2!h-!xDateWritten:~14,2!m-!xDateGMT:~17,2!s-%xFolder:~4,2%-%xFolder:~6,2%%%~xA"
```

Into this

```
set "xHour=!xDateWritten:~11,2!"
if "!xDateWritten:~17,2!"=="PM" set /a "xHour+=12"
set "xName=%xFolder:~0,2%-%xFolder:~2,2%-!xDateWritten:~6,4!!xDateWritten:~0,2!!xDateWritten:~3,2!-!xHour!h-!xDateWritten:~14,2!m-!xDateGMT:~17,2!s-%xFolder:~4,2%-%xFolder:~6,2%%%~xA"
```

---

Full Script (Added Comments)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Create Empty Folder
rd /Q "%Temp%\Temp" 2>nul & mkdir "%Temp%\Temp"

:: Loop through Folders
pushd "xPath=c:\processing"
for /d %%D in (*) do call :Process "%%~fD"
popd
goto End


::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:Process <Parent>
:: Folder Name
set "xFolder=%~nx1"

:: Set Sub Folder
if not exist "%~1\VIDEO\" goto :eof
pushd "%~1\VIDEO"

:: Loop through Videos
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir *.avi /b') do if exist "%%~fA" (
    rem Retrieve the file time stamp
    set "xDateWritten=%%~tA"
    rem Retrieve the Seconds using RoboCopy
    set "xDateGMT=0000/00/00 00:00:00"
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%X in ('robocopy . "%Temp%\Temp" "%%~nxA" /TS /FP /NS /NC /NP /NJH /NJS /NDL /L') do set "xDateGMT=%%X %%Y"
    rem Retrieve the Video frame information
    set "xFrame=00,00000"
    for /f %%X in ('exiftool -p "$Framerate,$Framecount" "%%~fA"') do set "xFrame=%%~X"
    rem Retrieve the file size
    set "xSize=%%~zA"
    rem Adjust to 24 hours
    set "xHour=!xDateWritten:~11,2!"
    if "!xDateWritten:~17,2!"=="PM" set /a "xHour+=12"
    rem Format = FF-FF-YYYYMMDD-HHh-MMm-SSs-FF-FF.ext
    set "xName=%xFolder:~0,2%-%xFolder:~2,2%-!xDateWritten:~6,4!!xDateWritten:~0,2!!xDateWritten:~3,2!-!xHour!h-!xDateWritten:~14,2!m-!xDateGMT:~17,2!s-%xFolder:~4,2%-%xFolder:~6,2%%%~xA"
    rem Display, Rename, and Save
    echo !xName!
    ren "%%~fA" "!xName!"
    echo !xName!,!xSize!,!xFrame!>>C:\RenameOutput.csv
)
popd
goto :eof


:End
endlocal
pause
```