# Finishing touches / tweaks to batch file renamer for video

Tags: datetime, batch-file, rename, batch-processing

Current code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Create Empty Folder
rd /Q "%Temp%\Temp" 2>nul & mkdir "%Temp%\Temp"

:: Loop through Folders
pushd "xPath=c:\processing"
for /d %%D in (*) do call :Process "%%~fD"
popd
goto End


::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:Process <Parent>
:: Folder Name
set "xFolder=%~nx1"

:: Set Sub Folder
if not exist "%~1\VIDEO\" goto :eof
pushd "%~1\VIDEO"

:: Loop through Videos
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir *.avi /b') do if exist "%%~fA" (
    set "xDateWritten=%%~tA"
    set "xDateGMT=0000/00/00 00:00:00"
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%X in ('robocopy . "%Temp%\Temp" "%%~nxA" /TS /FP /NS /NC /NP /NJH /NJS /NDL /L') do set "xDateGMT=%%X %%Y"
    rem Format = FF-FF-YYYYMMDD-HHhMMmSSs-FF-FF.ext
set "xFrame=00,00000"
for /f %%X in ('exiftool -p "$Framerate,$Framecount" "%%~fA"') do set "xFrame=%%~X"
set "xSize=%%~zA"
set "xName=%xFolder:~0,2%-%xFolder:~2,2%-!xDateWritten:~6,4!!xDateWritten:~0,2!!xDateWritten:~3,2!-!xDateWritten:~11,2!h-!xDateWritten:~14,2!m-!xDateGMT:~17,2!s-%xFolder:~4,2%-%xFolder:~6,2%%%~xA"
echo !xName!
ren "%%~fA" "!xName!"
echo !xName!,!xSize!,!xFrame!>>C:\processing\RenameOutput.csv
)
popd
goto :eof


:End
endlocal
pause
```

I previously believed my folder structure would be ex:

> C:\processing\15010107\Video\files.avi

, but it's actually

> C:\processing\15010107\Video\filedate\files.avi

, so I need it to search 1 more subfolder down than it was before.

Also, the renamed files need to have **24hr format** for the time, it's currently outputting the pm time but without a pm flag, which can get mixed up with the am files.

Comment: In regards to the 24 hour format, I replied to your comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072264/addition-of-output-file-for-renaming-video-batch

Comment: Is the new subfolder dynamic in name or static (always `filedate`)?  If it is static just change `if not exist "%~1\VIDEO\" goto :eof`  `pushd "%~1\VIDEO"` into `if not exist "%~1\VIDEO\filedate\" goto :eof`  `pushd "%~1\VIDEO\filedate"`

Comment: no, the folder would not be static, itd be whatever the date the video was recorded on. case in point we got some pm footage from yesterday, and am footage from today so we had two folders in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that these changes should cover your new issues.

1. Changed the Folder Loop to also Loop through the sub `filedate` folders.
2. The `Process` function now takes two parameters the `parent` folder and `current` folder.
3. The Hour is now adjusted to 24 hour format.

Full Script (Added Comments)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Create Empty Folder
rd /Q "%Temp%\Temp" 2>nul & mkdir "%Temp%\Temp"

:: Loop through Folders
pushd "xPath=c:\processing"
for /d %%D in (*) do if exist "%%~fD\VIDEO\" (
    pushd "%%~fD\VIDEO\"
    for /d %%S in (*) do call :Process "%%~fD" "%%~fS"
    popd
)
popd
goto End


::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:Process <Parent> <Working>
:: Folder Name
set "xFolder=%~nx1"

:: Set Working Directory
if not exist "%~f2" goto :eof
pushd "%~f2"

:: Loop through Videos
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir *.avi /b') do if exist "%%~fA" (
    rem Retrieve the file time stamp
    set "xDateWritten=%%~tA"
    rem Retrieve the Seconds using RoboCopy
    set "xDateGMT=0000/00/00 00:00:00"
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%X in ('robocopy . "%Temp%\Temp" "%%~nxA" /TS /FP /NS /NC /NP /NJH /NJS /NDL /L') do set "xDateGMT=%%X %%Y"
    rem Retrieve the Video frame information
    set "xFrame=00,00000"
    for /f %%X in ('exiftool -p "$Framerate,$Framecount" "%%~fA"') do set "xFrame=%%~X"
    rem Retrieve the file size
    set "xSize=%%~zA"
    rem Adjust to 24 hours
    set "xHour=!xDateWritten:~11,2!"
    if "!xDateWritten:~17,2!"=="PM" set /a "xHour+=12"
    rem Format = FF-FF-YYYYMMDD-HHh-MMm-SSs-FF-FF.ext
    set "xName=%xFolder:~0,2%-%xFolder:~2,2%-!xDateWritten:~6,4!!xDateWritten:~0,2!!xDateWritten:~3,2!-!xHour!h-!xDateWritten:~14,2!m-!xDateGMT:~17,2!s-%xFolder:~4,2%-%xFolder:~6,2%%%~xA"
    rem Display, Rename, and Save
    echo !xName!
    ren "%%~fA" "!xName!"
    echo !xName!,!xSize!,!xFrame!>>C:\processing\RenameOutput.csv
)
popd
goto :eof


:End
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: found time to give it a run today and worked perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: I managed to figure out adding 
move /-y "%%~fA" "c:\Processing Output\"
myself to move all renamed files to 1 output folder ready to be copied off to their destination all together. =) As a side question, when you added your comments to the script, whats the difference between using the :: and the "rem"? same thing two ways? or what

Comment: @Shiken  Glad to hear you are learning. **`:)`**  The `rem` "remark" is an actual command that will be processed but ignored since it is the true comment methodology.   The `::` double colon is a hack on the single colon `:` label specifier.  The double colon does not get processed by the batch script and is therefore faster, but has some script crashing issues if not used correctly within parentheses `()`.  Therefore, unless you want to learn all of the gotchas, I would recommend using rem within parentheses.  Here is a good discussion http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4204